# Identificar cada dispositivo en nodejs

Tags: nodejs, express

Estoy tratando de registrar cada dispositivo que se loguea en mi app, algo así como lo que hace facebook al mostrarte los dispositivos en los que has iniciado session.
Estaba impleentando esto con la IP la cual pude obtener de la petición de forma facil con el siguiente codigo

```js
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

app.get("/", (req, res)=> {

    const ip = req.header('x-forwarded-for') || req.connection.remoteAddress
    console.log(`La ip del usuario e ${ip}`)

})

app.listen(3000, ()=>console.log("app listening in the port 300"))
```

Esto funciona bastante bien, sin embargo la ip del cliente suele ser dinamica y cambiar cada X cantidad de tiempo, debido a esto luego de que la ip cambie, no puedo reconocer al cliente.

Leyendo un poco descubri que la dirección MAC podria ser una opcon perfecta, pero que no se puede obtener sino la del propio servidor.

Debido a lo anterior busco cualquier parametro del objeto request o de donde sea, que se pueda obtener y funcione como identificador unico del dispositivo del clinte.

Comment: una cookie a lo mejor? de todos modos el usuario puede limpiar sus cookies o visitarte con otro browser. la política en general es respetar la privacidad del visitante antes que la recolección de data, incluso con fines científicos